# After upgrading to 18.04 from 17.10 dual monitor stopped working, nvidia works with incorrect resolution, intel graphics card does not

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, 18.04, multiple-monitors

On my Dell system, the NVIDIA card gets recognized, but my Intel card does not after upgrading to 18.04 (17.10 was fine).
The NVIDIA graphics card resolution is incorrect though.
I have also tried the nouveau and NVIDIA proprietary drivers with no luck.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)`

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO UART #0 (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01)

$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1600/423x1200/317+0+0  default
$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 1600 x 1200
default connected primary 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200      0.00* 
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, Installed nvidia-390 driver and rebooted today and it worked.
I hate computers :)

Comment: It would be good for other users if you provide a detail answer about how have you installed driver and other required steps.